# What's wrong with my Trigger? Stop Task from being reassigned when Opportunity Ownership Changes

Tags: trigger, opportunity, tasks, ownership

```
    trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity(after update) {
    List<Id> newOwnerOpps = new List<Id>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.New) {
        if (opp.OwnerId != Trigger.Oldmap.get(opp.Id).OwnerId) {
            newOwnerOpps.add(opp.Id);
        }
    }
    List<Task> restoreTaskOwner = new List<Task>();
    if (!newOwnerOpps.IsEmpty()) {
        for (Task tsk : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :newOwnerOpps AND IsClosed = false]) {
            if (tsk.OwnerId == Trigger.Oldmap.get(tsk.WhatId).OwnerId) {
                tsk.OwnerId = Trigger.Oldmap.get(tsk.WhatId).OwnerId;
                restoreTaskOwner.add(tsk);
            }
        }
        if (!restoreTaskOwner.isEmpty()) {
            update restoreTaskOwner;
        }
    }
}
```

Old Owner = User A, New Owner User B

1. User A creates a task for User A, when owner changes task still assigned to User A
2. User A creates a task for User B, when owner changes, task still assigned to User B
3. User C creates a task for User A, when owner changes task is still assigned to User A
4. User C creates a task for User D, when owner changes task is still assigned to User D
   basically, task owner NEVER changes on ownership change

Currently, this works for scenarios 1, 2, and 4, but not scenario 3.

What is wrong with my trigger?

Comment: As written, it looks to me like the trigger will not work for _any_ of the scenarios (except 2, which should require no action), because that `if` condition is tautological - it's checking for X and then doing an assignment X. Is that a typo in the post?

Comment: Is there a way to correct my opportunity trigger to fit all four scenarios without also creating a task trigger?

Comment: I'm happy to post an answer (it looks to me like you just need to change `==` to `!=`), but I'm trying to square what I'm seeing with your description since it doesn't look to me like it should work _at all_ right now.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here, the trigger shouldn't work for any of the scenarios (except Scenario 2, which if I understand correctly is the OOTB behavior) due to what I think is just a typo:

```
if (tsk.OwnerId == Trigger.Oldmap.get(tsk.WhatId).OwnerId) {
    tsk.OwnerId = Trigger.Oldmap.get(tsk.WhatId).OwnerId;
```

The `if` condition should be `!=`.